# Asp.Net Core Error: InvalidOperationException: The view '11c8d3ac-b5f4-47c0-8d68-b1704f2fdc43' was not found

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using a link to an action in a controller that includes a asp-route-id and when I click the link I get this error. the asp-route-id is a parameter to to the ConfirmDelete action but it seems like .net core is looking for a view with the name that matches the value passed for asp-route-id and I get the following error:
InvalidOperationException: The view '11c8d3ac-b5f4-47c0-8d68-b1704f2fdc43' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Account/11c8d3ac-b5f4-47c0-8d68-b1704f2fdc43.cshtml
/Views/Shared/11c8d3ac-b5f4-47c0-8d68-b1704f2fdc43.cshtml

My link in the Index view is as follows:

```
  <a asp-action="ConfirmDelete" asp-route-id="@user.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

My Confirm Delete Action in the same controller AccountController is

```
 public IActionResult ConfirmDelete(string id)
   {
      return View(id);
   }
```

My Index and ConfirmDelete views are both in the folder Views/Account with the names Index.cshtml and ConfirmDelete.cshtml; In my Startup.cs I have the following route defined

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: Hint - you are passing a string. And string is usually the view name...

Comment: I think thats the issue because when I used the same code in another controller but passing int it worked. so how do I fix it

Comment: Click the duplicate link I provided.

Comment: `return View("ConfirmDelete", id);`

Comment: I tried return View("ConfirmDelete", id); and it works. Thanks a lot.